# after array crunch i get array likes this [[10,9,7],[6,5,4],[3,1]] , but i want to foreach loop for all elements of array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, loops, foreach

Here is my code , i want foreach loop for all element of arrays

```
 $all_users  = \App\User::orderBy('id','desc')->pluck('id')->toArray();
               $all_user = array_chunk($all_users, 3);
             foreach($all_user as $numbers){
                 foreach($numbers as $number){                   
                    return $all_firebase_tokens = \App\UserDeviceId::WhereIn('user_id',$number)->pluck('firebase_token')->toArray();
                }
            }
```

Comment: `return` is blocking the next iteration here...

Comment: how can i check without return

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jaquarh mentioned, the very first iteration of the foreach loop will stop the whole function by already returning a value. Assuming what you need is an array of the firebase_tokens, something like this is likely what you need:

```
$all_users  = \App\User::orderBy('id','desc')->pluck('id')->toArray();
$all_user = array_chunk($all_users, 3);
$all_firebase_tokens = [];
foreach($all_user as $numbers){
    foreach($numbers as $number){                   
        array_push($all_firebase_tokens, \App\UserDeviceId::WhereIn('user_id',[$number])->pluck('firebase_token')->toArray());
    }
}
return $all_firebase_tokens;
```

Comment: sir i am getting this error 


Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::cleanBindings() must be of the type array, int given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\fetnation\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder.php on line 919

Comment: `[$number]` should work fine. The second parameter should be an array when using `whereIn`. [Refer to the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#additional-where-clauses) before you ask basic syntax questions.

Comment: I assumed that line of your code worked. I've edited the answer to reflect the syntax error Jaquarh just mentioned.

Comment: Please close the question by accepting the answer to help future viewers.

Answer (score 0):

Simple and small code snippet, **you can easily loop on $arraySingle** :

```
$array = [[10,9,7],[6,5,4],[3,1]];

$arraySingle = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);

print_r($arraySingle);
```

Output will be like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 10 [1] => 9 [2] => 7 [3] => 6 [4] => 5 [5] => 4 [6] => 3 [7] => 1 
)
```